# Full week in planning view in Outlook?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

Please look at the picture below.

I want my (6) calendars vertically (schedule view) and a whole week in view. My current view only displays 2.5 of the 7 days. Time cannot be set with a larger interval than 60 minutes, the sizer on the bottom right does not go smaller than 90%....

[image]

I can drag the left border (at Monday 9:00) more to the left, but that isn't much.

(Buying a larger monitor or setting the Windows font size smaller are not an option.)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the scroll bar at the bottom to view the entire week:
[image]

If it is acceptable to use horizontal view, an alternative is that you can use Week view and overlay all the calendars, press Ctrl+F1 to collapse the ribbon.
[image]

Comment: This does not meet the essential requirements from my question: I want the **whole week in view**, and **vertically**.